# Re-use alert dialog view without destroying it's contents

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to use an alert dialog in Android without destroying the view and it's contents or state.

For example, I am inflating the dialog with a view that contains some edit text fields. I want to enter values into these fields, then hide the alert dialog, then later show the alert dialog again with all the values still in the same state.

My application needs the user to type comments (using the alert dialog) about content on the view, then go back to the main view, continue working and reading, then add more comments. I know I can save these values into variables or sqlite3 database, however, it feels like such a workaround when I can just keep the view without destroying it, and when I open the dialogue again, it does not inflate the view again and recreate the view again, replacing the old view.

I have tried the following:

```
//Class variables

private AlertDialog.Builder builderSave = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private View layout = null;

//In my code where I create the dialog ...

try {
    if (builderSave == null) {
        //inflate view for layout for the first time.
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_id_form, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
        builderSave = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builderSave.setView(layout);
    } else {
        //niks
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //daar was n nullpointer exception...
}
```

However, I get an error when trying to display the dialog the **2nd time** :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Answer (score 0):

But saving the data in between really isn't a workaround...it's more like the standard behavior. What you're trying to do actually sounds like a workaround for the way Android handles views and could potentially result in memory leaks.

May I suggest that your problem could lie mainly in your apps architecture? Maybe you can provide some more code to make your architecture more clear or why you would find it difficult to store data in between showing dialogs.

Off the top of my head, using an MVVM approach I'd suggest something like this:

```
public class SomeViewModel {

    private String myComment;

    public String getMyComment() {
        return myComment;
    }

    public void saveMyComment(String myComment) {
        this.myComment = myComment;
    }

    // All other viewModel stuff
}
```

And for the view:

```
public class SomeView extends Fragment {

     private Dialog myDialog;
     private SomeViewModel viewModel;

     /* All the Fragment setup
       * ...
       * ...
       */

     private void initDialog() {
         /* Init Dialog relevant stuff
           * ...
           * ...
           */

         myDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

             @Override
             public void onDismiss(DialogInterface Dialog) {
                 final String newComment = "get comment from Dialog text field";
                 viewModel.saveMyComment(newComment);
             }
         }
     }

     private void showDialog() {
         final String previousComment = viewModel.getMyComment();
         if(previousComment != null) {
             // Set as content on dialogs EditText
         }
         myDialog.show();
     }
}
```

I think your problem is, that conceptually you see the EditText content as part of the view layer/viewState, where I'd argue it should be seen as belonging to the model/data layer.

Comment: Daniel W, Thanks for the answer above. It is definitely something I think we can have a nice debate about. To be honest, I prefer saving data into a database and using it later.

I have a few specific cases where I think it makes more sense to keep the state of the view. The alert dialog and the main view share the same work / context, so in my case, users draw on the main view and then make comments about the drawing on the alert dialog, however, they have to navigate back to the main view to see what was drawn, then navigate back to the alert dialog and make comments about it and continue.